# Unable to find PHP error in WordPress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

The following PHP code is in my WordPress functions.php file. I can't seem to find the problem. Hopefully someone can see it somewhere. I've even run this through an online PHP phraser and it detected no errors.

Error:

[image]

```
<?php
function iconic_format_price_range( $price, $from, $to ) {
return sprintf( '%s: %s', __( 'from', 'iconic' ), wc_price( $from ) );
} 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_price_range', 'iconic_format_price_range', 10, 3 );




// removing the price of variable products
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );



add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 
'selected_variation_price_replace_variable_price_range');
function selected_variation_price_replace_variable_price_range(){
global $product;

if( $product->is_type('variable') ):
?><style> .woocommerce-variation-price {display:none;} </style>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var p = 'p.price'
        q = $(p).html();

    $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function( event, data ) {
        if ( data.price_html ) {
            $(p).html(data.price_html);
        }
    }).on('hide_variation', function( event ) {
        $(p).html(q);
    });
});
</script>
endif;
}
```

Comment: You need `<?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So before the endif and after your jQuery is over you need to resume php.

```
</script>


<?php  //this guy is missing
endif;  
}
```

Another way, maybe more appropriate since there is no interpolation, is not to quit php.

```
function iconic_format_price_range( $price, $from, $to ) {
return sprintf( '%s: %s', __( 'from', 'iconic' ), wc_price( $from ) );
} 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_price_range', 'iconic_format_price_range', 10, 3 );




// removing the price of variable products
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );



add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 
'selected_variation_price_replace_variable_price_range');
function selected_variation_price_replace_variable_price_range(){
global $product;

if( $product->is_type('variable') ):

echo "<style> .woocommerce-variation-price {display:none;} </style>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var p = 'p.price'
        q = $(p).html();

    $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function( event, data ) {
        if ( data.price_html ) {
            $(p).html(data.price_html);
        }
    }).on('hide_variation', function( event ) {
        $(p).html(q);
    });
});
</script>";
```

Regarding the style, I dunno how that would work. Maybe there are some other issues with the code. I have not run it.
** I assume that the error does not point to a line in the file is not because debugging is switched off, wp_config

```
//DEBUGGING
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Lastly an IDE like visual editor with php and wordpress extensions would be useful to you.